# Election metadata is too close to the top divider

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-election

I think the new design looks great, but on [election pages](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4) the sidebar meta-text is too close to the top divider:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live after our next production build.